# Website sometimes takes long time to load

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, php, lamp

I am running a LAMP system with Ubuntu 14.04. I have 4 cores and 8GB Ram on my server

The problem is that when I connect to my website after idle period( 2-3 hours or more) the it takes lot of time to load. Some times around 60-110 seconds.

The website loads slow in 2 scenarios

1) This happens when website is idle for 2-3 hours or more.In the second attempt and afterwards, after accessing the website after idle period in The website loads in 8-10 seconds.

2) I also have an RSS fees which runs every one hour. The website also takes 60-70 seconds while the RSS feed runs.

Please let me know how to solve the problem.

Adding Stuff

First image is when RSS is not running in cron and second one is when RSS is running in cron

[image: Top without RSS]
[image: Top with RSS]
Output from free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       3981       4003          0        183       1943
-/+ buffers/cache:       1855       6130
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: can you show logs ?

Comment: Is the site public? Sometimes load times can have something to do with the content it's serving....

Comment: Hi Ashish, Can u please let me know what logs you want to see.I will post on Github

Comment: Hi Ashish, I have put output from top command

Comment: Do you use mod-php or PHP-FPM ?

Comment: Hi Ashish, I use mod-php

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably caused by a **memory issue**. Swapped out memory to be precise. There must be some sort of a memory intensive task running in the idle period, and all your Apaches, phps, and others get **swapped out**. Once you try to connect, they get **swapped in**, but it takes a long time. Once they are back in memory, everything works fine. Solution:

1. Add more memory to your machine.
2. Make the crucial processes less swappable by using **cgroups**.

Before you do that, diagnose your memory usage, system load, the swapiness parameter to verify that this is indeed the culprit.

Comment: Hi Konrad Gajewski, I have 8GB of RAM, All the time at least 4-4.5 GB of Ram is free after system and user usage. I have not set swap memory since I have free memory.

Comment: I'm gonna leave the answer, as it usually is the case. Provide your memory, system load and task load parameters nontheless.

Comment: Hi Konrad Gajewski. I have put output from top command

Comment: Give output of `free -m` as well. Is this when the site is fast, or slow?

Comment: The first image without RSS is when site is fast. Second one is  with RSS is when site is slow